# The case of "id" attribute when signing an element in a XML file

Tags: xml, signature, xml-signature

Is the case of the "id" attribute important, when creating a reference to an element for digital signing following xml-dsig standard?

I've seen attributes named "ID", "Id" and "id" and some software packages have trouble finding the correct element/node for different forms.

Also following various specs and schemas, there are different id attributes expected.

For sure the attribute must be named "id", but is the case specified or are there only recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

The essential problem is two-fold. First, as you know, XML is case-sensitive.

Second, XML does not "define" the **name** of an ID attribute. Unlike HTML which says elements may have an 'id' attribute, XML by itself does not. There is the concept of an `xs:ID` type, but the name of the attribute (e.g., `ID`, `Id`, `id`, or `myIdentifier`) is not provided by default.

For reference see [W3C How should the problem of identifying ID semantics ... be addressed...?](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/xmlIDsemantics-32.html).

So, some parsing software assumes `id`, some assume any of `id`, `ID`, `Id`, some assume none.

More specifically, I typically see the usage of `ID` in SAML signing. The commonly used command `xmlsec1` does not identify a name to use, so you have to. For example:

```
xmlsec1 --decrypt --privkey-pem /foo/key.pem --id-attr:ID EncryptedKey my.xml
```

tells xmlsec1 to declare the named `ID` attribute, on `EncryptedKey` nodes (only) to be a known xs:ID attribute. It appears to additive: you can do mulitiple:

```
xmlsec1 --decrypt ... --id-attr:Id EncryptedKey --id-attr:ID EncryptedKey --id-attr:id EncryptedKey
```

will use any on EncryptedKey nodes.

(You can declare `foobar` to be an xs:ID attribute, and it will work just fine, so if your source XML has something like:

```
<node foobar="1234"/>
<otherNode URI="#1234"/>
```

use:

```
xmlsec1 --id-attr:foobar node ...
```

Answer (score 1):

*(Note: You must know that I am not an xml-dsig expert, so I am only answering as far as XML, DTD and XML Schema are concerned.)*

XML is case sensitive, so the case is important and must be the same as in the DTD or Schema which you are using.

Of course if applications use different schemas with different cases, there is a compatibility issue.

I looked at the official W3C specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/ and the Schema and DTD seem to specify "Id". Is this the specification you are using?

Also, it might be confusing to know that the corresponding DTD type is "ID" and that there is an XQuery function called "id".

Comment: I have no problem in understanding the importance of case-senstivity as far as XML and schema goes, have designed plenty of both...
I have "problems" using references for signing XML elements.

Which part of xmldsig-core does specify the case of target id attribute? 

I can see for example that the xml-dsig element Signature has a upper case Id as an attribute. 

But where does it say that the "target" attribute, the one being used as a reference in the SignedInfo.Reference element, must be upper-case?

Comment: Say I want to sign the Data element of this xml:

<Document><Data id="myRef">blah blah blah</Data></Document>

Which case should the attribute "id" be? 
Pay attention, there is no schema involved!

Most of the software I've used works with "id" or "ID" or "Id". Some works only with "Id".

But is there a rule about it?

Anyway, the xml parser should somehow "guess" where the signature reference points, since it doesn't know the schema and attribute types...